# Is it possible to call java static string in jsp?

Tags: java, string, jsp, static

Assume I have a java class like this:

```
class Link {
   public final static UPDATE = "/update";
}
```

Is it possible to call Link.UPDATE in the JSP like below:

```
<form method="post" action="${Link.UPDATE}">
</form>
```

I tried but it doesn't work. Is there any technique similar to that?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". In any case, I didn't think even current JSP EL allowed unfettered access to arbitrary classes and their functionality, but I'm a version behind, too.

Comment: *I tried but it doenst work.* What exactly not working ?Are you getting any exception/error?

Answer (score 0):

You may be want something like

```
<form method="post" action="<%= Link.UPDATE %>">
</form>
```